# FullCalendar support for Google and Exchange (Outlook)

Tags: fullcalendar, integration, exchange-server

I noticed that FullCalendar has support for Google but noticed a lack of mention for Exchange

Does FullCalendar support Exchange integration?

Additionally how does the data model work for FullCalendar and two-way data synchronization of the calendar events - is this beyond the scope of the component or is there a solution for this as well.

Another way to tackle this would be to synch the Exchange calendar events with Google and use the Google API for the calendar data. Is that the proposed solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, FullCalendar doesn't have built-in Exchange calendar integration. You have to implement it by yourself using Exchange Web Services Managed API, Exchange Web Services or other integration methods described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Syncing Exchange events with Google calendar and displaying them later in FullCalendar using Google Calendar Plugin is an option, but please be aware that FullCalendar Google Plugin is designed for displaying public calendars only.

Comment: Thanks for the response - after doing some additional research it seems that EWS provides as REST API that makes support both on-prem Exchange installations and Office 365 (cloud) solutions transparent and compatible from an API perspective (we will see about that once I try it of course). I could sync with Google but that seems like a rabbit hole that I do not want to venture down unless I have to

Comment: @Whatty can you share some insights? Did you ever integrate with Exchange and if so - how was it? Tnx